# Manipulate Marionette ItemView using its cid

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

`// Global scope` 
`A1= Marionette.ItemView.extend({ ... });` 
 
`// Inside a function, local scope` 
`var a1= new A1;`

When I `console.log(a1)`, where `a1` is defined as shown above.
I see that a1 has a unique 
`cid: "view32"`

My question is how can I get hold of View `a1` (where `a1` is a local variable inside a function) using its `cid`. Does Marionette have a global object (there must be one - imo) containing the list pair of (reference to) Views currently rendered in the DOM and their respective cid's? 
 
(P.S. I am not talking about a user created global `Marionette.Application()` object but an object which Marionette uses internally to keep track of currently rendered Views in DOM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Marionette's view cids are in fact Backbone's view cids which are being generated upon [object creation](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1221) using [underscore.js' uniqueId](http://underscorejs.org/#uniqueId) method. View instances are not being held in global context.